# C# string extension method to check type xml/json/csv

Tags: c#, xml, json, csv

I'm trying to write a web api service for importing the incoming data in the database. The data coming in will be in either XML or JSON or CSV string format. Depending on the type of string the service will instantiate its respective processing engine to ingest the data through a stored proc.

I can certainly write three separate controller methods for three formats but since the incoming datatype is always going to be string, I want to write just one method in that I'll check the type of incoming string to see if it's of type xml, json or csv.

I was planning to extend a string class to check its type. Is anyone aware if something like this already exists? I did some search but couldn't find anything relevant.

Comment: A CSV string could always be mistaken for something else, right?  `"<A>,<B>,</B>,</A>"` looks like XML but is also could be a CSV string with HTML tokens in the columns.

Comment: The data might have a header or enough info to identify it of which type, you may want to show some samples of each type

Comment: Check out [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/), there is a free one at the bottom of the download to test out / use. It will do all the api's for you, you just create the classes to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the request header should contain the content-type:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type:

text/csv : comma-separated values ; RFC 4180.
text/xml : Extensible Markup Language ; RFC 3023.
or
application/json

after that, optionally, you can create a web api csv formatter: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters (in the link the formatter do not handle deserialization) and pass your type to you web api method with a strong type.

Comment: I like your idea of checking for content-type of the header. I used that and instantiate the respective processing engines that I've configured in my web.config to process the incoming string. Works like a charm! Thanks :)